# Why does this weird syntax oddity involving async exist in Python?

Tags: python, asynchronous, syntax, python-3.5, python-3.6

I have this small bit of code in a file (`small.py`):

```
def async(foo):
    pass

def bar(foo):
    pass

async def bar(foo):
    return None

async def async(foo):
    return None
```

When I do `python3.6 small.py` it issues this complaint:

```
  File "small.py", line 7
    async def async(foo):
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I comment out the last two lines of the file it works fine.

What's going on here? Why is it perfectly fine to have `def async` but not OK to have `async def async`?

Additionally, I have this file (`small2.py`):

```
def async(foo):
    pass

def bar(foo):
    return async(foo)

async def baz(foo):
    return async(foo)
```

And when I do `python2.6 small2.py` I get this:

```
  File "small2.py", line 8
    return async(foo)
               ^
```

But if I change `baz` to call `bar` instead of `async` it works just fine. How do I call `async` inside of `baz`?

Comment: You've already defined the first function with the same name. So,...

Comment: @Coldspeed - Redefining identifiers in that way in Python is just fine. I've updated my question to make it clear that this isn't what's causing the problem.

Comment: *"Why is a particular identifier perfectly fine in one context and forbidden in another?"* What do you mean? It's a syntax error each time you use it as an identifier. Where is it perfectly fine? You're using it as a syntax keyword in the other case.

Comment: @ParticlePaul - Then why does the first `def async` not trigger an error if `async` is a syntax keyword? That's the 'two different contexts' I'm referring to. Why is the first `def async` just fine, but `async def async` is somehow not?

Comment: `async` & `await` won't be keywords [until 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#new-keywords); until then their use should trigger a DeprecationWarning.  I'd guess that the SyntaxError is a result of [PEP-492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492) which introduces a number of SyntaxErrors for using `async` / `await` forms out of an async context (though I don't see this particular behaviour specified).

Comment: @snakecharmerb - So you're saying that in Python3.7 the first line would error out and I wouldn't be able to declare a function named `async`?

Comment: @Omnifarious that's my understanding, yes.

Comment: As a sidenote, I find it interesting how downvote means "I don't understand this question and can't answer it." for some people.

Comment: @snakecharmerb - It sounds like you have part of an asnwer. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I was hoping someone would answer this, but nobody has with the correct answer.

The problem is that in Python 3.5 and 3.6, the words `async` and `await` are keywords, but only sometimes. Other times they play the role of identifiers.

The only time `await` is a keyword is inside of a function declared `async def`. And the only time `async` is a keyword is just before `def` or inside an `async def` function. Of course, in the `async def async(foo)` case, the second use of `async` is an attempt to use it as an identifier inside an `async def` and so it fails because there, it's a keyword.

This is kind of weird, as all other keywords are always keywords everywhere. For example, you can't use `while` as an identifier ever.

This situation will change in Python 3.7 and both `async` and `await` will be keywords everywhere, just like every other keyword.

It's this way in Python 3.5 and 3.6 because they didn't want to just spring a new keyword on everybody right away. When you add a new keyword, lots of people might have identifiers that have the same name as your new keyword, and so those identifiers become illegal and people have to change their code and may get all kinds of weird errors until they do.

The answer to how to use an identifier named `async` or `await` inside of an `async def` function is that you don't. You have to use `getattr` or alias the object the identifier refers to or otherwise arrange it so that you do not use the words `async` or `await` in your `async def` function as anything other than the keywords they are there.

This is described a little, though the implications are not really thoroughly worked through, in the [transition plan section of PEP 492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#transition-plan).

As a side note, redefining names in Python is just fine. One might better think of `def foo` as `foo = lambda` (except that lambdas are limited to single expressions in Python). So, assigning a new function value to `foo` causes no problems and is simple and well defined.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is you are using the reserved keyword async as your function name so when ever you try to invoke it. It tries to call the async keyword rather than the function which has been overridden by the same.

To demonstrate this more clearly in a directory create two files one with name `requests.py` another one as `test.py.` Now if you use `import requests`([python library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)) and use any of it's methods in `test.py` it ll throw you an error. Because the file `requests.py` overrides the library `requests`.

The same scenario happens here. You have declared a function with name `async`. Also you have declared a async method later which overrides the method with name **async**. Hence whenever you call async it tries to call async method. Since `async` is a **reserved keyword** and no longer a function which has been overridden, it reports error. To fix this change the function name from async to something else.

```
'''def async(foo): #overrides async coroutine hence now async refers to this function.
    pass'''

def asyn(foo):
     pass

def bar(foo):
    pass

async def bar(foo):
    return None

async def asyn(foo): # aync refers to above commented method in your code rather than coroutine.
    return None
```

Also the same happens with the later case of your question.

Comment: I didn't think Python had return types.

Comment: Sorry updated the answer. Ping ne in chat for any other queries.

Comment: This isn't exactly wrong, but it isn't exactly correct either. And it is much better than your first answer. :-)

Comment: I posted my own answer.